# DRY with TypeScript and constructor that takes options object

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0

I have this code:

```
export interface LDAPPoolOpts {
  id: number;
  size: number;
  connOpts: any;
  active: Array<any>;
  inactive: Array<any>;
  dn: string;
  pwd: string;
  waitingForClient: Array<Function>
}


export class Pool {

  id: number;
  size: number;
  connOpts: any;
  active: Array<any>;
  inactive: Array<any>;
  dn: string;
  pwd: string;
  waitingForClient: Array<Function>;

  constructor(opts: LDAPPoolOpts) {}

 }
```

as you can see the constructor for this class simply takes an options object with type: `LDAPPoolOpts`.

*My question is: how can avoid repeating myself by having to declare the exact same fields for both the class and the options object interface?*

You cannot extend an interface..and implementing an interface does not mean you inherit the interface's fields.

Should I declare a type instead of an interface?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in that you cannot extend an interface and implementing the interface requires you to write out the properties again. Although this solution alters the structure of your class, one way is to create a property on the class with the interface type.

```
export interface LDAPPoolOpts {
    id: number;
    size: number;
    connOpts: any;
    active: Array<any>;
    inactive: Array<any>;
    dn: string;
    pwd: string;
    waitingForClient: Array<Function>
}


export class Pool {
     opts: LDAPPoolOpts;

     constructor(opts: LDAPPoolOpts) {
         this.opts = opts; // assign to the property how you see fit
     }
}
```

Comment: yeah that might be a good solution, will clean things up a bit. Definitely annoying to have to keep a list of the same exact properties in two different places.

Answer (score 2):

What I frequently use is the following:

```
export class Pool {
    // ...

    constructor(initializer?: Partial<Pool>) {
        if (initializer) {
            Object.assign(this, initializer)
        }
    }
}
```

This, of course, assumes that the class has the same properties as the supposed initializer object, so this is essentially very similar to object initialization in C#. This approach works best if you are also initializing your instance members to meaningful default values.

Comment: thanks, can you explain what the parameter <Pool> does in your code?

Comment: @AlexanderMills `Partial<Pool>` is the same as `Pool`, except every single property (including each method) is optional. I.e. you can do `new Pool({ id: 1337 })` without TypeScript throwing errors about missing properties. Without `Partial<T>`, you'd have to specify every single property in the initializer object, _including any methods_.

Answer (score 1):

**2020 UPDATE**

Now it's possible to do what you want with minimal boilerplate:

```js
interface LDAPPoolOpts {
    id: number;
    size: number;
    connOpts: any;
    active: Array<any>;
    inactive: Array<any>;
    dn: string;
    pwd: string;
    waitingForClient: Array<Function>
}

interface Pool extends LDAPPoolOpts { }
class Pool {
    // Pool has all the properties of LDAPPoolOpts
    // no need to copy stuff over
}

// if you want to export, make sure its on a different line
export default Pool;
```

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/340#issuecomment-184964440